# 'SubConstructor' is assignable to the constraint of type 'B', but 'B' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BaseConstructor'

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I am new to generics I made a design where we use generic so that it increases code flexiblity. But in my case I have a weird issue where the get the above error. My requirement is that I want to able to pass the value from a child class of a sub class of a base class to the base class to do an operation in the base class and return back the value to the child class. I have attached my code snippet here.
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOAIQOAB4AVOUGYAOwBMjSVgBhCetKAV22gA%20OAG8AUHElwwUCHWzBG02WACMALjiUAPrybAAZgEt6igNxiAvmLGhIsOHgJEAyrySsKxGiDpMWZJzc6PwwQj5%20zCRk5MTC4lKOXDyh0AAUAJSiEolSKLxgwFCZOblwMAAWRigAdDIQanAAvHCmAO5wbkhBKQLFAOQAEkXA-RmlcNbWtuDQOPiE0Ww9IX3ZifXydEpGjACEmvS8ALZIRVY2M-bzzp3uK3xrtAxRng%20pUAlSAPTfcCgQY7AZQNIowIzAFATfJIAAKKg0-3QJgA5s04P1%20hNMMlVmFijD4Q1ETxUVkvmV8oViuMypJKtUaoSEejmcSJlMbHY5o4Fq53G8qrglM9-HcPDEuoKjML3n14tjcY98Zl1nSqUUSolOVceU5FlLAkLGHL8REXgFlkqPmrJDD2MaiWBDiczlB0QAGRXBZXpe2OlQu05FckTRIamlhqQM2r%20mWMJ2s%204Bhoci5iIA)

Here you can find the error and help me refactor my code so that I can bring in all my operations at the base level or help me solve this error with any work arounds for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be solved by passing an optional generic in the place of **subBase** class. I have attached the code for your reference. I have added
the comments for the required area so that it would be helpful for someone in future

```js
export abstract class Base<T extends BaseConstructor> {
    protected prop1: T|undefined;
}

export class SubBase<B extends BaseConstructor> extends Base<SubConstructor | B> { // add optional generic here as the super class doesnt know which type to pass but the child class very well knows
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.prop1 = new SubConstructor('Here')
    }
}

export class BaseConstructor {
    protected id!: number
}


export class SubConstructor extends BaseConstructor{
    // some properties
    subProp1: string = ''
    constructor(subProp1: string) {
        super()
        this.subProp1 = subProp1
    }
}

export class SubBaseChild extends SubBase<SubBaseChildConstructor> {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}

export class SubBaseChildConstructor extends BaseConstructor {
    subChildProp: number = 0
    constructor(subChildProp: number) {
        super()
        this.subChildProp = subChildProp
    }
}
```

Hope this would help you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error message might be an explanation to you:

> Type 'SubConstructor' is not assignable to type 'B'.
> 'SubConstructor' is assignable to the constraint of type 'B', but 'B' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BaseConstructor'.

I cutted off the generic constraints here. Not sure, if it really helps in your context:

```html
export abstract class Base {
    protected prop1: BaseConstructor|undefined;
}

export class SubBase extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.prop1 = new SubConstructor('Here')
    }
}

export class BaseConstructor {
    protected id!: number
}


export class SubConstructor extends BaseConstructor{
    // some properties
    subProp1: string = ''
    constructor(subProp1: string) {
        super()
        this.subProp1 = subProp1
    }
}

export class SubBaseChild extends SubBase {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}

export class SubBaseChildConstructor extends BaseConstructor {
    subChildProp: number = 0
    constructor(subChildProp: number) {
        super()
        this.subChildProp = subChildProp
    }
}
```